# Reading Shakespeare

Tags: anti-semitism, literature

Is someone allowed to read Shakespeare, as Shakespeare was an anti-Semite (ex/ Merchant of Venice)?

Is someone's not allowed to, what should he do if he's in a situation where he cannot avoid it, such as a school?

Comment: Who exactly was not anti-Semit (apart from Jews) at this time? I want to ask, are you sure that Shekespeare was particularly antisemite, or he was as most non-Jew at this time.

Comment: That's why I don't read Ma Tovu at schacharis.

Comment: @ClintEastwood I try to understand what is problematic in ma tovu but I don't understand

Comment: @kouty, it was said by the anti semite, Billam.

Comment: To read Shakespire can teach you alot of things, Chochma Bagoym Taamin. Tora Al Taamin. Tora is all true and all good, Bagoym, you can find good things and true things, but you need to know that everything would be examined if good or not.

Comment: Actually, Shakespeare was not really an anti-Semite. When Merchant of Venice is **properly** staged, the anti-Semites are actually held up for ridicule and Shylock is actually shown to be a victim. For example the hypocrisy of the *Quality of mercy* speech, the final court ruling and the seduction of his daughter.

Comment: Seconding @sabbahillel there are a variety of ways of understanding the text and its relationship to author. I can make the case that whether Shakespeare was or was not an anti-semite cannot be evinced from this play. If the question were asked on a more generic level and if it focused on the artistic expression as connected to the personality of the artist, it might be better.

Comment: @Danno true. It can be a principle that the great author can write a character that has various traits that are not like him. Similarly, I have seen actors who could play a despicable character that is nothing like him and get blamed as if he is like the character.

Comment: There is no prohibition.

Comment: lightly related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61741/is-one-allowed-to-read-books-written-by-homer-such-as-the-iliad-or-the-odyssey

Comment: Perhaps @M. Broder could tell us why he thinks that it might be forbidden to read the writings of an anti-semite? Aren't all books written by non-Jews likely to contain inappropriate material or reflect non-Torah views? If the question would be about reading all books from non-Jews, I would understand where the question is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

A Ma'aseh Rav permitting this is [Rav Zevin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Yosef_Zevin)'s halachic essay (in [Le'or Hahalacha](https://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=144241&width=0&scroll=0&udid=0)) on the very book you discuss.  He obviously found it permissible to read and write about, so I can't imagine it would be prohibited...

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, the essay doesn’t betray that R. Zevin was familiar with the entire narrative -and possibly may not have read it- rather he deals with the plot’s (Shylock’s) central monetary arrangement from a *halachic* perspective.